# What will be the distance of a point from black hole where we will not experience its relativistic effects?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes

Could you please tell me what will be the distance from the singularity of a black hole to a point outside of the black hole where we will not feel its gravitational pull or where it's relativistic effects will be zero?

Will it be any multiples of Schwarzschild radius?

Is there is any formula to calculate the same?

Comment: Why do you think there would be some cutoff distance?

Comment: Because at certain point we will not feel it's gravitational pull right?

Comment: It might not be strong enough to feel or even measure but it’s there. It never goes to zero. It just gets smaller and smaller as you get further and further away.

Answer (score 1):

No, there will never be such a distance. The gravitational attraction and relativistic effects will get smaller and smaller but never really vanish. This doesn't apply to black holes only: any gravitational source will do.

Comment: But at certain point it will be zero right? Even though it can't be actually zero... So what will be that distance? I know it will depend upon the mass of Black Hole...

Comment: As you say, it can't be actually zero. It will get very, very, very small at long distances, *approaching* zero, but it will never **be** zero.